# Angular module for moment-range

Tags: angularjs, momentjs, angular-moment

I am using [angular-moment](https://github.com/urish/angular-moment) to use momentjs in my angular project. I like that I can simply incluse the moment variable into my constructor to use moment in my controller.

Is there a similar angular module for [moment-range](https://github.com/gf3/moment-range)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe that there is no angular specific module built for this.

But I also don't think there is a need for one. Angular moment exists as a module because not only it hooks momentjs library to your app but it also provides with angular specific filters & directives.

So just do a `bower install moment-range` and reference the js file. Then you are good to go with using the bits in any of your angular controllers.

Comment: How to use in a composant?

Comment: @sgrillon at the moment of the writing this answer refers to Angular JS 1.x. For later versions of angular and components please post a new question.